# Display image in REACT

Tags: reactjs, jpeg, fetch

I am getting an image from backend and trying to display it on the front end using react.
I guess that I am not setting properly image into the file when I fetch it.
Because, I have the response from the service:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAg ...
```

And this is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          file: []
        }
}
fetchPicture(){
     const {match} = this.props
     const id = match.params.id
     const { file } = this.state;
     fetch("/hunter/picture?page=" + id)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(file => this.setState({ file }));
   }

render() {
    return(
    <Form>
        <img alt="" src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${this.state.file}`}/>
    </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

The most important, I have this on my console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
```

When I send it from backend, I am setting content type of jpg.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
```

Could be also the reason for not displaying because react expects json format?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're calling `res.json()`, it tries to parse your image as json and fails.

Comment: oh, okay. I got rid of this line with getting json. is there any suggestion how to properly get an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use fetch and to parse it as json or base64 when you can just set it as src:

```
<img alt="" src={"/hunter/picture?page=" + this.props.match.params.id} />
```